# Why isn't this str.join() looping properly?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, concatenation

I've seen a lot of tutorials online for adding integers  + lists, but I'm still a little fuzzy on joining strings. I can't seem to get this to loop properly. The final output should be "hi!!!" but it only returns one iteration.

```
input_string = "hi"
more_char = "!"

def add_strings(input_string, more_char):

  for output_string in input_string:

    output_string = input_string
    if len(output_string) > 5:
      break
    while len(output_string) < 5:
      while True:
        if len(output_string) < 5:
          output_string = "".join(input_string + more_char)
          return output_string
        elif len(output_string) == 5:
          return output_string

  return str(output_string)

print(add_strings(input_string, more_char))
```

Comment: `join()` is used to combine a list into a string. `input_string` and `more_char` are alreay strings, you don't need to use `join`.

Comment: Also, by calling `return output_string` you break 
the loop ;)

Comment: You should be using `break` instead of `return output_string`. That stops the loop but doesn't end the function.

Comment: Your function is the equivalent of: `return input_string + more_char`

Comment: Why do you need nested loops?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using something like `"hi" + 3*"!"`?

Comment: the whole thing should be `return input_string + more_char * (5 - len(input_string))`

Comment: @Barmar Would that answer still work if the input_string was greater than 5? What happens when the value becomes negative? ie. more_char * (5 - 7)?

Comment: @Bozo Multilpying a string by a negative number returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you meant to repeatedly add the second string onto the first until its length is 5 or more:

```py
def add_strings(input_string, more_char):
    output_string = input_string
    while len(output_string) < 5:
        output_string += more_char

    return output_string

input_string = "hi"
more_char = "!"
print(add_strings(input_string, more_char))
```

Output as requested

Comment: Ok, now I see where I was confused. I read that I should avoid using '+=' as much as possible so I was trying to do this through a series of elifs, but I see putting conditionals inside of the while was causing problems. Is "+=" the optimal case here?

Comment: Check the answer from @Barmar in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loop at all. You can repeat a string by multiplying it by the repetitions.

```
def add_strings(input_string, more_char):
    if len(input_string) < 5:
        output_string = input_string + (5 - len(input_string)) * more_char
    else:
        output_string = input_string
    return output_string
```

You don't really need the `if`, because multiplying by a number less than 1 returns an empty string. But it makes the intent clearer, IMHO.